# sql - select composite primary key with condition to one of the primary key

Tags: sql, mysql, relational-division

Here is a table with `id` and `permission` as composite primary key, which means one can have some permissions.

```
id    permission
1     'A'
1     'B'
2     'A'
3     'B'
```

Now I want to select all `id`s that fit some conditions. For example:

1. `id` **WITH** permission 'A' **AND** 'B'.
2. `id` **WITH** permission 'A' **AND WITHOUT** permission 'B'.

I've come up with a kind of sql which uses `exists` clause.

For 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.id FROM t t0
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id = t0.id AND t1.permission = 'A')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id = t0.id AND t1.permission = 'B');
```

For 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t0.id FROM t t0
WHERE
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id = t0.id AND t1.permission = 'A')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id = t0.id AND t1.permission = 'B');
```

It works, but for large tables, it is slow because it traverses the table multiple times for each record. So I wonder if there is a faster and clearer way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Note that this is a classic Relational Division With Remainder (or Without Remainder if you want id where *only* those two are present)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for case 1. Here is the sample:

```
SELECT id
FROM permissions
WHERE permission IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT permission) = 2;
```

And you can use `NOT IN` for case 2. Here is the sample:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM permissions
WHERE permission = 'A'
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM permissions
    WHERE permission = 'B'
);
```

It should be faster than your initial query that querying exists and/or non exists twice. Here is the [fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/WoAVH48K).

Comment: Thanks! The solution for case 1 is really good and works when the condition grows. For the solution to case 2, I assume that additional SELECT is needed when more conditons are added?(like with permission 'A' and without permission 'B' and without permission 'C')

Comment: No need to add select explicitly. You can change `=` with `IN`. So, it would be like this `SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM permissions
WHERE permission = 'A'
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM permissions
    WHERE permission IN ('B','C')
);`

Comment: So it looks like I can combine these two solution to select id with any conditions? For example if I want id with 'A' and with 'B' and without 'C' and without 'D', It would be like `SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM permissions
WHERE permission IN ('A', 'B')
AND id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM permissions
    WHERE permission IN ('C', 'D')
)
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT permission) = 2;
`

Comment: Yes, correct. Here is [sample fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/hPg75DZ_)